# Java+sqlite REAL field to String

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm using Sqlite with Java using [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/). When querying sqlite, I've found out that these two return different things:

```
String str = result.getDouble("field_name").toString();
String str = result.getString("field_name");
```

The latter implicitly rounds up the digit of the REAL number in sqlite, and converts it to String. The former doesn't do the round up thing.
Is this a bug of sqlite JDBC implementation or is this a common sense in SQL queries?

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by `REAL number`? Is it getting converted to integer before finally converted to string?

Comment: sqlite's data type is not type-safe, and does not conform to sql standard. this is intentional as this is a *lite* database.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari: REAL is a data type of SQLite, which doesn't have DOUBLE or FLOAT instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not a bug, definitely. In the former, `toString()` method of `Double` class is invoked. Whereas, in the latter case, SQLLite implementation is working.

Comment: +1: SQLite and Java have different code for doing the conversion between IEEE double-precision floats and strings, and that's an operation that it is *very* hard to get right.

Comment: Thank you. So it is the SQLite implementation of JDBC which trim the REAL value to form a String, right?